# What is it wanting me to create a method?

Tags: java, swing, bufferstrategy

I am trying to create the menu for the game I am working on but when I try and use GetBufferStrategy it Eclipse tells me to create a method. I don't want a method. I want it to get the buffer strategy. I am kinda new to java so please explain why my code is wrong so I don't repeat it again.

```
package homeScreen;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class homeScreen {

    static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    public static final int WIDTH = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    public static final int HEIGHT = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();

    BufferedImageLoader imageLoader = new BufferedImageLoader();

    private static homeScreen home = new homeScreen();

    private BufferedImage backgroundImage = null;
    private BufferedImage Buttons = null;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        home.loadImages();
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            backgroundImage = imageLoader.loadImage("/res/HomeScreen.png");
            Buttons = imageLoader.loadImage("/res/MainScreenButtons.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        home.display();
    }

    private void display(){
        BufferStrategy buffStrat = this.getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = buffStrat.getDrawGraphics();

        if(buffStrat == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        g.dispose();
        buffStrat.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't extend from anything, therefore `this.getBufferStrategy()` does not exist within the context of you class.

Try extending from `java.awt.Canvas` instead

Having said that, be careful mixing heavy and light weight components, they tend to not play well together.

I would also avoid `Toolkit.getScreenSize()` as it does not take into account any "additional"  elements (like the task bar) that might be present on the screen.

You "could" use `frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` instead...